# Are the illustrations part of Shel Silverstein's poems?

Tags: poetry, shel-silverstein

Shel Silverstein's poems are illustrated by himself. The illustrations often provide the 'punchline' of the poem, as in the following examples (all taken from *Falling Up*.

**Safe**

> I look to the left,
> I look to the right,
> Before I ever
> Move my feet.
> No cars to the left,
> No cars to the right,
> I guess it's safe
> To cross the street...

This poem is accompanied by this illustration:

[image: a safe falling out of the sky onto the girl's head]

This is a safe falling out of the sky onto the girl's head.

**Unfair**

> They don't allow pets in this apartment.
> That's not decent, that's not fair.
> They don't allow pets in this apartment.
> They don't listen, they don't care.
> I told them he's quiet and never does bark,
> I told them he'd do all his stuff in the park,
> I told them he's cuddly and friendly, and yet -
> They won't allow pets.

This is accompanied by this charming animal:

[image: cartoon of a child leading an elephant sized cat on a leash]

**Web-Foot Woe**

> Us swans and geese
> Have rotten luck.
> You folks don't know
> Whose name is whose.
> I waddle in -
> You all yell "*Duck*."
> Can't you see
> That I'm a *goose*?

With this pointed picture:

[image: a pointed spear is flying towards the goose]

**Imagining**

> You're only *imagining*
> A mouse is in your hair.
> You've got to stop imagining
> That mice are everywhere.
> I think you're just imagining
> To give yourself a scare,
> But trust me dear, I wouldn't lie:
> There is *no* mouse up there.

With this slightly surprising picture:

### [image: cartoon elephant perched atop a girl's head]

I've made the point; there are more examples. So can these illustrations be considered part of the poem itself, as they are necessary to understand the poem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Maybe you could better define what you mean by "part of the poem"?

Comment: @Shokhet - I'm essentially asking if it's on the same level as the text.

Comment: This is a really good question. Great work!

Comment: @Shokhet are the illustrations there for decoration? Or do they change/contribute the meaning of the poem? When interpreting the poem, how should the illustrations be taken into account?

Comment: If that is the question, @Hamlet, then I think it's fairly obvious that they *do* change the meaning of the poem. Just look at all the examples that Mithrandir provided -- he practically answered the question himself.

Comment: I think it's more Hamlet's last point, @Shokhet. How do the illustrations affect (effect?) the meaning of the poem? Are they on the same level as the text?

Comment: (Affect.) I just don't understand how you could read these in a way that they're *not* on the same level as the text. Mr. Silverstein did, after all, illustrate these books himself, and "Safe," for example, wouldn't say much without the accompanying image. Cc @Hamlet.

Comment: @Shokhet maybe this question could be improved if it asked about a specific poem. But I think there is still things to talk about in this question. Answers could discuss, for example, how the publishing process for these poems changed, given how poems are typically published without accompanying images.

Comment: @Hamlet Changing the question to ask about publishing process invalidates Lauren's answer (and probably justifies a separate post). I agree that it would be much better if Mithrandir asked about a specific poem; [I had already said as much in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1037?m=38285551#38285551). Absent a specific difficulty in understanding, this question more or less sounds like "Is this fairly obvious hypothesis about these poems accurate? Here's way more than enough material to prove it." (No offense meant, Mith.)

Comment: Fun fact: [Shel Silverstein and Johnny Cash were good friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shel_Silverstein#Songs)!

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to say that with some of them, yes.

There are some of Silverstein's poems where the illustration is humorous but not required, such as "My Beard" (from *[Where the Sidewalk Ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_the_Sidewalk_Ends)*):

> My beard grows down to my toes,
>   I never wears no clothes,
>   I wraps my hair
>   Around my bare,
>   And down the road I goes.

While the picture of a little man wrapped in his beard running down the street is funny, you don't need it to understand the text. But in the examples you've cited, without the image, you literally can't understand the punchline (the safe falling, the elephant in the girl's hair).

So yes, for some of them (obviously you'd have to go through his work and read them to figure out which), the illustration is part and parcel of the text, and cannot be separated.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered this post from the bygone ages of the Stack Exchange abyss, and I thought I could contribute an answer to it, so excuse my tardiness.

I most certainly agree that Shel Silverstein intended his poetry to be read devoutly with his delightfully morbid illustrations. And on the point of your question, here is some evidence of a poem (albeit shorter than usual) which entirely fails to succeed without the illustration:

[image]

"**Draw a crazy picture, / Write a nutty poem**, / Sing a mumble-gumble song, / Whistle through your comb. / Do a loony-goony dance / 'Cross the kitchen floor, / Put something silly in the world, / That ain't been there before." -Silverstein