# How is the connection between the picture on page 59 and the last line of "Allison Beals and Her 25 Eels" shown in other publications of the poem?

Tags: poetry, shel-silverstein

"Allison Beals and Her 25 Eels" is a poem in *Falling Up* by Shel Silverstein. It describes how Allison uses 24 eels -- as shoelaces, earrings, ladle, etc. The 25th, however, is different. The poem ends like this:

> The 'lectric one was a lamp that could shine,
>   And one got a new job on page fifty-nine.

You can see an eel half off the page (bottom left corner):

> [image]

And then, if you flip back (the poem is on page 98) to page 59, you can see an eel being used as a wire:

> [image]

**So is the page-59 eel shown in other publications of the poem<sup>1</sup>? If so, how?**

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Which, IMO, it *should* be, as I think it's [actually a part of the poem](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/are-the-illustrations-part-of-shel-silversteins-poems).</sub>